# Absolutely positioning the corner of a rotated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/nkqsnmwm/) so far:

I have a parent div and another div inside it that's rotated 6 degrees.

The CSS for the parent div is:

```
#side-left {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And the rotated triangle:

```
.solid-triangle {
    background: #c9dee2;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 110%;
    width: 145px;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
    transform: rotate(6deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

Basically, I want the top of the black border to be in the top right corner of the parent div, like so:

[image]

I can get it to line up by adjusting the absolute positioning on the right (currently 0) but the values get messed up when the height of the parent div changes (due to adding more/less text on the right-hand side).

I've seen a few jQuery solutions for 90 degree rotations, but none of them worked with my 6 degree rotation.

Comment: 8.1 degrees seems to hit the top right https://jsfiddle.net/nkqsnmwm/2/

Comment: just Change `top: -120px;` and you can see the Change

Comment: Here, your (Fiddle) [https://jsfiddle.net/nkqsnmwm/5/]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have sorted this for you.

Your transform origin was upside down you wanted top right instead of bottom left.

and change left from `0px` to `-145px`

---

https://jsfiddle.net/nkqsnmwm/3/

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main-wrap {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#side-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#side-left {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.solid-triangle {
  background: #c9dee2;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 110%;
  width: 145px;
  top: -10px;
  right: -145px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-wrap">
  <div id="side-left">
    <div class="solid-triangle"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="side-right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tincidunt magna, vitae iaculis erat. Sed vel risus dolor. Sed dictum convallis luctus. Nulla ac odio placerat, molestie ante maximus, malesuada ipsum. Proin pharetra imperdiet
      metus ut vestibulum. Phasellus pharetra, tellus sit amet viverra ultrices, sapien tellus lobortis nisi, nec placerat nisl purus nec lacus. Sed neque risus, fringilla ac elit ac, placerat porttitor nisl. Donec nec facilisis nulla, in iaculis justo.
      Fusce in mi eros. Sed semper felis rhoncus, sodales purus sed, semper massa. Morbi laoreet, purus non dignissim aliquet, ante nulla malesuada ligula, dignissim finibus nulla tortor vel ex. Nullam quis efficitur libero. Sed pellentesque sodales lacinia.
      Donec vitae faucibus purus, sed luctus lacus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tincidunt magna, vitae iaculis erat. Sed vel risus dolor. Sed dictum convallis luctus. Nulla ac odio placerat, molestie ante maximus,
      malesuada ipsum. Proin pharetra imperdiet metus ut vestibulum. Phasellus pharetra, tellus sit amet viverra ultrices, sapien tellus lobortis nisi, nec placerat nisl purus nec lacus. Sed neque risus, fringilla ac elit ac, placerat porttitor nisl.
      Donec nec facilisis nulla, in iaculis justo. Fusce in mi eros. Sed semper felis rhoncus, sodales purus sed, semper massa. Morbi laoreet, purus non dignissim aliquet, ante nulla malesuada ligula, dignissim finibus nulla tortor vel ex. Nullam quis
      efficitur libero. Sed pellentesque sodales lacinia. Donec vitae faucibus purus, sed luctus lacus.</p>

    <p>Aliquam lacinia sagittis dolor, a consequat felis blandit in. Praesent at orci mi. Nunc imperdiet semper rhoncus. In lectus ipsum, scelerisque vel nulla nec, auctor bibendum lectus. Pellentesque dictum purus diam, et vulputate eros varius vel. Nunc
      tempor nisi a tellus ornare feugiat. Sed dignissim, turpis sed mollis fermentum, purus eros vestibulum nulla, at viverra neque dui sit amet metus. Donec euismod libero luctus diam imperdiet, a vulputate arcu malesuada. Proin tincidunt aliquam dui,
      nec efficitur nisi laoreet ac. Proin faucibus, purus eget aliquet pretium, est ex dapibus massa, ut malesuada lectus dolor sit amet ante. Morbi volutpat enim vel ex tempor imperdiet. Phasellus pretium felis non libero accumsan, sed ultricies nulla
      iaculis.</p>

    <p>Morbi ac sagittis nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut nulla ante, efficitur eu tincidunt a, vestibulum sit amet urna. Vestibulum tristique aliquam lacus vitae consectetur. Mauris euismod velit sit amet orci commodo, in consectetur urna rutrum. Duis ut
      turpis ac lacus accumsan tincidunt vitae eget tortor. Curabitur lacinia nibh mattis lacinia varius. Quisque posuere felis eget mollis sagittis. Vestibulum lacinia volutpat leo ac dignissim. Pellentesque sodales metus at massa malesuada vulputate.
      Sed vehicula magna ut sapien sodales suscipit. Praesent dictum convallis diam, sed faucibus felis rutrum quis. Morbi convallis rutrum dui et varius. Vestibulum dapibus imperdiet dolor, at sollicitudin risus accumsan in.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me by 30sec. Exactly what I found for it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was also missing that right: -145px; I had tried a top right origin before but totally missed that negative right position.

Comment: Ah sorry failed to mention the left:-145 I thought you had already mentioned messing with it updated my answer to show the left ammendment.

Answer (score 0):

Change to solid-triangle class like that

```
.solid-triangle {
  background: #c9dee2;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95px;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform: rotate(6deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this and it will work correctly:

```
.solid-triangle {
    background: #c9dee2;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 110%;
    width: 145px;
    top: -120px;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
    transform: rotate(6deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue. As soon as the height of the containing DIV is different, the triangle will be out of alignment.

Comment: Oh yep you are right.. Didn't check that scenario out.

Answer (score 0):

Smallest way to achieve.. just add  `position: inherit;`

```
#side-right { 
 width: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This might have worked for your resolution but on any sort of re-size the triangle will move.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the rotation reference to (**transform-origin: left top;**)
and move all the shape right to -width value. In your case **right: -145px**;

So:

```
.solid-triangle {
    background: #c9dee2;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 110%;
    width: 145px;
    top: -10px;
    right: -145;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
    transform: rotate(6deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
}
```

Hope it will do for you :)